# How to change my id and name in php url

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

How would I change the URL from

from: `example.com/games.php?id=27`

to: `website.com/games/271/game-name-here`

So far I have this in .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^games/([0-9]+)/?$ games.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*).aspx$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^(.*).ashx$ $1.php
Options -Indexes
<Files 403.shtml>
order allow,deny
allow from all
</Files>

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

Options -Multiviews
```

Comment: I wrote an answer about implementing "friendly URLs" on StackOverflow recently: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32115217/implementing-friendly-urls-using-htaccess/32136534#32136534

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, you want requests for the following URL `website.com/games/271/game-name-here` to be handled by games.php

For this, you may use a simpler rule.

```
RewriteRule ^games/(.*)$ /games.php?var=$1 [L]
```

This will send all requests with /games/ to games.php. For e.g.

`/games/271/game-name-here` will go like this `/games.php?var=271/game-name-here`

Now, `game-name-here` is only for SEO purpose as what you actually need is only the id. So, filter the id part from the var like this -

```
$value=($_GET['var']);
$temp = explode('/',$value);
$id = $temp[0];
```

Remember, htaccess is used only for handling the URL requests. You still need to form the correct URLs in your webpages.

Additional Tip: You may also consider the following URL structure `website.com/games/271-game-name-here` . Here just explode the URL on a hyphen '-' instead of '/'

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to do two things :

1. `.htaccess` to decode the url and send it to abc.php
2. You need to change the file that create the URL. If the page that refer to `abc.php?vid=55` is `index.php`, you need to change your code in `index.php`

For example:

old program

```
$query = "SELECT id,title FROM vid_table";
$result = mysql_query($query);

while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo '<a href="abc.php?vid=' . $data['id'] . '">' . $data['title'] . '</a>';
}
```

new program

```
while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo '<a href="abc.php/vid/' . str_replace(" ", "-", $data['title']) . ">' . $data['title'] . '</a>';
}
```

In `abc.php` you need to change the way the program read from the database

```
/* this means that the page get redirected from .htaccess */
if (isset($_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL'])) 
{
    $parts = explode('/', $_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL']);

    array_shift($parts);

    $url_name = $parts[1];
    $url_name = str_replace("-", " ", $url_name);
    $query = "SELECT id FROM vid_table WHERE title = '$url_name'";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $data = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $_GET['id'] = $data['id'];
}
```

Then you can continue with your program and can go to second step and URL rewriting.

More information:
http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/introduction-to-url-rewriting/

I hope it's not too confusing.

Comment: This answer is inconsistent. In the first code snippet PATH_INFO is used (ie. `abc.php/path/info`) to create a more friendly looking URL (which is different to what the OP requires). If PATH_INFO is used then you don't necessarily need to do any rewriting in .htaccess, but your second code snippet implies that you are.